# python: replacing values in a dataframe with values from another dataframe at specific indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
d = d = {'ID': [31,42,63,44,45,26], 
     'lat': [64,64,64,64,64,64],
     'lon': [152,152,152,152,152,152],
     'other1': [12,13,14,15,16,17],
     'other2': [21,22,23,24,25,26]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 ={'ID': [27,48,31,45,49,10], 
     'LAT': [63,63,63,63,63,63],
     'LON': [153,153,153,153,153,153]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

`df1` has incorrect values for columns `lat` and `lon`, but has correct data in the other columns that I need to keep track of.  `df2` has correct `LAT` and `LON` values but only has a few common IDs with `df1`.  There are two things I would like to accomplish.  First, I want to split `df1` into two dataframes: `df3` which has IDs that are present in `df2`; and `df4` which has everything else. I can get `df3` with:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame()
for i in reduce(np.intersect1d, [df1.ID, df2.ID]):
    df3=df3.append(df1.loc[df1.ID==i])
```

but how do I get `df4` to be the remaining data?

Second, I want to replace the `lat` and `lon` values in `df3` with the correct data from`df2`.
I figure there is a slick python way to do something like:

```
for j in range(len(df3)):
    for k in range(len(df2)):
        if df3.ID[j] == df2.ID[k]:
            df3.lat[j] = df2.LAT[k]
            df3.lon[j] = df2.LON[k]
```

But I can't even get the above nested loop working correctly. I don't want to spend a lot of time getting it working if there is a better way to accomplish this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, you can use boolean indexing:

```py
m = df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)

df3 = df1[m]
df4 = df1[~m]

print(df3)
print(df4)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  lat  lon  other1  other2
0  31   64  152      12      21
4  45   64  152      16      25

   ID  lat  lon  other1  other2
1  42   64  152      13      22
2  63   64  152      14      23
3  44   64  152      15      24
5  26   64  152      17      26
```

---

For question 2:

```py
x = df3.merge(df2, on="ID")[["ID", "other1", "other2", "LAT", "LON"]]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  other1  other2  LAT  LON
0  31      12      21   63  153
1  45      16      25   63  153
```

---

EDIT: For question 2 you can do:

```
x = df3.merge(df2, on="ID").drop(columns=["lat", "lon"])
print(x)
```

Comment: The above answer works great.  Thank you! But, on my actually dataset I have 300+ columns, so listing out the columns in `x = df3.merge(df2, on="ID")[["ID", "other1", "other2", "LAT", "LON"]]` is not practical. Is there away to indicate keeping all other columns without listing them?

Comment: @ChloePeterson I've updated my answer. For the last step just drop the columns `"lat"`, `"lon"`. The `"LAT"`, `"LON"` will have new values.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge with indicator True and then keep preference for `LAT` and `LON` and fill the rest by `lat` and `lon`, then use the indicator and a grouper and create a dictionary. Then grab the keys of the dictionary:

```
u = df1.merge(df2,on='ID',how='left',indicator='I')
u[['LAT','LON']] = np.where(u[['LAT','LON']].isna(),u[['lat','lon']],u[['LAT','LON']])
u = u.drop(['lat','lon'],1)
u['I'] = np.where(u['I'].eq("left_only"),"left_df","others")
d = dict(iter(u.groupby("I")))
```

---

```
print(d['left_df'],'\n--------\n',d['others'])

   ID  other1  other2   LAT    LON        I
1  42      13      22  64.0  152.0  left_df
2  63      14      23  64.0  152.0  left_df
3  44      15      24  64.0  152.0  left_df
5  26      17      26  64.0  152.0  left_df 
--------
    ID  other1  other2   LAT    LON       I
0  31      12      21  63.0  153.0  others
4  45      16      25  63.0  153.0  others
```